# Unity 3D : How to face up card only Half

Tags: unity-game-engine

Dears, As i am new to unity i am unable to figure out the issue for card face up.
In simple words i would like to flip the card partially instead of facing up the entire card.
This is the way i looking for.

Can some one suggest me how to do that using unity2d/3d
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would be an awesome effect. You need to bend the card. You can do it with some "deformer" plugins on AssetStore. I found [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/deform-148425) take a look, it's free.

Good luck with your awesome game ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your card is a 3D object. In that case, there are 2 ways to do it: bake an animation in a 3D editor, like Blender, or do it real-time in your game.

Keep in mind, if you're a complete and total beginner, the 2nd option might go over your head. The first one is a lot simpler, but I suspect using a plugin as suggested by the other answer is by far the easiest.

## Bake an animation

I'm a novice at 3D art, so I don't know if this is the best approach, but you could add several bones (that's the term) to the card, starting from the "bottom" edge to the "top". This will act as a sort of spine, so that once you bind the card to the bones, moving the bones will bend the cards.

Make sure the mesh (think of it as the "flesh" or the "skin" of the object; though it's hollow inside, as all 3D objects are) is subdivided enough that it can be smoothly bent. This basically means more vertices (kind of), and I'll go more into that later.

Then you just record the animation keyframe-by-keyframe and export it to Unity to use it there. That's probably the smart way to do it; definitely better than programming the bend real-time.

Even if you want to control how much the card bends, you could probably do it with an animation.

## Real-time inside the game

But if you — or whoever else might read this — is dead-set on doing it in the game, here's how. You can achieve this effect by displacing the vertices.

#### Vertices and geometry

Vertices are essentially points that describe the geometry of a 3D object. A simple rectangle might have only 4 — one at each corner — but then you wouldn't be able to bend it even if you lift the "topmost" 2 vertices (an edge) on a card and leave the other 2 "on the table", because the plane is always straight.

To avoid this, you just need to add more vertices. The "bottom-most" pair of vertices remains on the table, the pair after that lifts slightly, the one after slightly more, etc. The more vertices you add, the smoother the bend, but too much and performance will suffer. You just need to find the balance between "looks good enough from this distance" and "kills my computer".

Note: you can add a thousand vertices and most computers won't have any trouble. But if the cards are only a minor part of the game, then that's too much processing power dedicated to something unnecessary. Or if you have hundreds of such cards, the computations will add up and tank the game's FPS.

#### The curve

There are a number of ways to get the curve you want. You could take the rising part of a sine wave and squish and stretch it, or you could just form the curve visually inside an [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html) (which you'll define inside a script and make public) and sample it for each vertex along the bend. This is probably how I'd do it.

AnimationCurves are essentially just a plot, with x and y axes. The x axis goes from 0 to 1, so you need to map each vertex's position along the edge that bends to a 0..1 range. This is pretty easy to do: just divide it's distance from the "starting" vertex (that's on the table) by the distance between the starting and "ending" vertices (that's in the air).

Then, call `Evaluate()` on the AnimationCurve to get how high it should be displaced, and multiply it with a modifier float to scale  it up and make the bend greater. (By default, the y axis goes from 0 to 1 as well. So, if you want the highest point to be, say, 2 units, multiply the return value by 2.)

#### Implementation

I suggest you do this with a C# script, on the CPU, because you can call a [convenient function for recalculating normals](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateNormals.html). I won't go into what that means, but just know that doing that manually on the GPU can be a massive pain. And that you need to do it to make lighting and shadows work right.

(Also, shaders are just plain harder.)

#### Guides

Brackeys has a video on procedural terrain generation, which is also mesh deformation, except instead of 1 curve the mesh is deformed to resemble terrain. They're beginner-friendly and easy to follow.

I don't know if they're grouped conveniently into a playlist, so look for them [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=brackeys%20procedural%20generation%20playlist). Start from *Mesh Generation in Unity - Basics*. You're not gonna be creating the mesh, just displacing its vertices, but it's useful to get a better understanding.